# boxing an int won't convert it to reference type?

Tags: c#, .net

Correct me if I am wrong boxing convert value type into reference type then why the following code give 10 output not 12?

```
public static void fun(Object obj)
    {
        obj =12;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value =10;
        Object obj = value;
        fun(obj);
        Console.WriteLine((int)obj);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: yes it gives 10 output

Comment: Of course it returns 10. When you pass a parameter into a method, the method "copies" that parameter. So the original `obj` is still unchanged. However the one in the `fun` method will be changed. This parameter copy thingy is called "Pass by value". If you don't want that to happen check out "Pass by reference"

Comment: You'd need to use `ref` keyword if you want to pass reference (change the object itself not its copy)

Comment: that's true for value type but for reference type it should change the value into 12

Comment: @Nofi try the same with a reference type and you will get the same

Comment: No, when you use a reference type, you pass a reference to the function. But you pass the reference _by value_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're not actually modifying the value of `obj` in your `Main` method when you call `fun`. The value is given to `fun` and changed there and only there since it is essentially a copy of that variable, as it is being passed by value and not by reference.

Either use the `ref` keyword:

```
public static void fun(ref Object obj)
{
   obj = 12;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int value = 10;
   Object obj = value;
   fun(ref obj);
   Console.WriteLine((int)obj);
}
```

or make your `fun` method return the new value:

```
public static Object fun(Object obj)
{
   obj = 12;
   return obj;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int value = 10;
   Object obj = value;
   obj = fun(obj);
   Console.WriteLine((int)obj);
}
```

Comment: if we can pass even a value type as a reference by adding ref then why do we have two separate types for variables(value type and ref type)?

Comment: Because you may not necessarily want to change the value of your variable when you pass it to another method that uses it.

Comment: we have to use ref keyword with both value type and reference type in order to pass them as a reference so why don't we just have a reference type because it will act as value type if we don't use ref keyword with it.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with boxing/unboxing. You are simply creating a new object in your method and replace the passed parameter with it. Since you didn't pass then parameter as `ref` the calling code is not affected.

Declare your method as

```
public static void fun(ref Object obj)
```

and change the call to

```
fun(ref obj);
```

then it will output 12.

Answer (score 2):

.NET function calls pass arguments by value, not by reference (except when you use `ref` or `out`). I.e. as soon as you assign something to a function's parameter *inside the function*, you do not see the change outside the function. Even though for reference types you pass references around, you still pass these references *by value*.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are passing value to your function as value type. You should pass object as reference type.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int value =10;
   Object obj = value;
   fun(ref obj);
   Console.WriteLine((int)obj);
}

public static void fun(ref Object obj)
{
    obj =12;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if its value type or reference type.
When you pass a variable to a function, you are assigning the parameter in the function with your variable. They both point to the same instance. but inside the function you are assigning a new value for it, so it is a new instance. the previous one of course will not change.

This is the same as:

```
object o = 10;
object o2 = o;
o2=12;
```

`o` is still 10, while `o2` is 12